# How can I link the youtube iframe to show popup message

Tags: html, youtube

I there a way to show popup texts while clicking the youtube video iframe code ?

```
<a href='login.html?sid=0&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=240&width=650' class="thickbox" title='test'>
```

Comment: What is your purpose behind doing this? The answer might help us answer your question. Also, do you only want the box to show up when you click on the iframe or do you want it to show up when you hover over it? And what is going to be in the box? Just text? And why did you put that line of code in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to call Javascript on the `onclick` attribute

```
<a onclick="alert('test')"
  href='login.html?sid=0&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=240&width=650' class="thickbox" title='test' >
```

This will open the pop up and then go to the URL (tested on Firefox 7).

**Edit:** Another solution is to do the href location after the pop up :

```
<a onclick="alert('test');document.location.href='login.html?sid=0&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=240&width=650'" 
  class="thickbox" title='test'>
```

Comment: @logudotcom See the edit, I post another solution, moving the href to on `onclick`.

Comment: alternatively, you may want to do a window.confirm, which gives the user an option of "Yes" or "No" on the buttons

Comment: @rickyduck I agree, but I don't know exactly the needed bahavior. the question talks about 'popup texts'. The author must adapt...

Comment: @Jean-Charles sure, of course, just thought I'd pop it on here in case he isn't aware of that functionality.